# How to display a complete SharePoint list row in InfoPath form

Tags: list, infopath, custom-form

I'm at creating a section in InfoPath13 where users can select an item (a certain job) that has a certain price and a certain number of hours to be spent on it.

I'd like to create form where users only need to pick from the item name and they will get the price and the hours to be spent automatically populated from the list connected via data connection.

Figure 1:

[image: SharePoint list the information should be pulled from]
Figure 2:

[image: The way it should look like in the form]

Comment: It is not clear if the form controls are a repeating table. It is not clear if the form controls are bound to the main data source or the secondary data source. It is not clear if you want to copy values or just display values that have been looked up. You need to provide more information. **Edit your question** to do that, then post a comment.

Comment: They could answer my question with the same details on an other forum. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to Hours column textbox property
2. In default view textbox, Click on Fx button
3. Click on Insert Field or Group..
4. Select secondary data source (Your list) from above dropdown
5. Select Hours field
6. Click on Filter button
7. Set condition like Item(Secondary data source) = Item(Main source
   Dropdown)
8. Save it
9. Same steps for Price field

Comment: Thank you for this Viraj. 
Unfortunately it hasn't sorted the issue.

Comment: What issue you are facing? There should be no issue on this

Comment: It does not pull all row data. 
Maybe I do something wrong - even if it seems to be so easy.

Comment: If you select First, it will pull 1 & 10 from secondary data source. Recheck all steps. You will get result. It might be issue regarding wrong condition. Check condition.

Comment: Sorry i have updated answer. I have written wrong condition. Please check it. Now it will work. Sorry again.

Comment: Do you might have any solution for the same in case of a Repeating table? 
Same solution does not work for some reason.

Comment: Please ignore. Same way works perfect.

Comment: Great. You achieve what you want.