# Preventing InfoPath from showing same value in each row (repeating table)

Tags: infopath, display-form, infopath-data-connections

I have a repeating table showing data from an external list. 
It is connected with further (hidden) columns in the list but the form 
only shows a few (3) columns from the (around) 8. 
First column is a drop down list and when I select an item it shows 
me the same value in each row even if selecting 3 different items. 
It seems the system pulls only one row data per group.

Can you please advise a formula or rule to be used?

[image]

One row down: 
[image]

Reference: 
[How to display a complete SharePoint list row in InfoPath form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178201/how-to-display-a-complete-sharepoint-list-row-in-infopath-form)

Comment: Hi Guido Matis, @Viraj Gorajia, I am facing same issue, so can you please suggest solution for it if you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add rule on dropdown control. When dropdown item changed, Rule will fire and set it to related hours and Price textbox.

> Add action: Set field's value, Add hours textbox and set value with
>   following steps. Same process for Price textbox.

1. Click on Fx button
2. Click on Insert Field or Group..
3. Select secondary data source (Your list) from above dropdown
4. Select Hours field
5. Click on Filter button
6. Set condition like Item(Secondary data source) = Item(Main source
   Dropdown)
7. Save it

Comment: Thank you @Viraj.
Now what happens - when selecting an item - is that it shows the price and hours but when I go with insert item, it copies the value from the first row and if I change the item for the second row, the price and hours remains the same.

Comment: Have you attached rule on dropdown?

Comment: Yapp. I was following the exact same steps. 
About the built-up of the form (repeating table section) - could be useful: 
1. I added a Multiple-Selection List Box, I added all necessary fields
2. I changed control to repeating table.

Comment: ..and I made a drop down list out of the first text box (within this repeating table). 
This displays the items - connected to a SharePoint list.

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of your added rule?

Comment: With this configuration,it should display the values of Price and Hour according to each dropdown selection.

Comment: Disable this rule. Try to set value in hours default value textbox. And test it again.

Comment: Try to enable Always Postback from dropdown property before set to default value in textbox.

Comment: I deleted the rules and tried first to disable "refresh value when formula is recalculated". 
This looks better now as I get the necessary value but the issue is that not in the same row but it puts that info in the next one (see screenshot). 
On the other hand it is important that the system keeps on showing the necessary value as it can happen that someone is going to change the first item (after adding 3) but if it does not "refresh value" they'll only get the result what they received when selecting the first item the first time.

Comment: Enable Always postback of dropdown

Comment: I've set that to Always. 
Strange thing is that even if it is a half solution it stops working after 4 items. 
Whatever Item I choose for the 5th, 6th, (etc), it gives the same value as the 4th one. 
I'm afraid I have a rule doing something wrong in the background.

Comment: You have changed the other controls in textbox and dropdown. Can you do it with fresh new controls. Take new repeating table and in subgroup add one dropdown and one textbox for hours. Because there should not be this type of problem.

Comment: I just recreated the repeating group and same thing happens. 
I even recreated the form itself and used this connection only but again the same issue. 
I'm sure there is only one checkbox somewhere to check or something like that but I can't find it.

Comment: It seems I've found an alternative solution. 
I'm going to test it right away and let you know if I still need any help. 
Thank you a lot for your continuous support.

Comment: I have tried this solution and it works smoothly.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mATsK0aVZ9I

Comment: Great.. Finally you found the solution.

Comment: Without your support I wouldn't have come to this point for sure so thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome Guido Matis. :)

Answer (score 0):

In Rules, use current() function so that is compared to the current row's field.
Example:

```
current()/../my:FieldNameForCompare
```